# Set Line6 AMPLIFi so that there is minimal ringing or feedback after strumming?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

I've been playing for about 18 months, and taking lessons the whole time. In the last 3 months, my Line6 amp has been ringing after playing. I use the Rock Clean setting tone on the amp. It could be just my bad playing, or it could be the settings on the Line6.

Any constructive suggestions on configuring the Line6 or adjustments would be helpful. I have tried all the different humbucker settings on my Ernie Ball St. Vincent guitar. Also tried to cycle through the Tap settings on the Line6. No real difference.

Comment: Take it along to your teacher, who maybe has met the problem  already. What exactly is 'ringing after playing'? Sounds like it could be reverb or echo that has inadvertently been left on.

Comment: I don't know much about amps but (like tim said) it could be the reverb or echo, also try adjusting the gain and high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both Tim and @unknown, I ended up resetting the Line6 to the factory default and that resolved it.

Comment: Please accept your own answer so that this question can be marked as resolved ;-)